# How to retrieve license information for the dependencies with Tycho in an Eclipse RCP application (Java)?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

We are developing a Java desktop application based on the [Eclipse RCP (E4)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP), and build with [Eclipse Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/), a tool to build Eclipse plugins and products with Maven.

In an Eclipse RCP, the dependencies are **not** defined in the Maven POM. Instead, they are defined in the OSGi manifests (`MANIFEST.MF`) (Eclipse plugins are OSGi bundles at their core).

Therefore, there is no Maven-native method to retrieve the licenses for dependencies via, e.g., the [Maven Notice Plugin](https://github.com/Jasig/maven-notice-plugin).

Is there a way to achieve automated retrieval of licenses (and perhaps even creation of a BOM/NOTICE) for Eclipse RCP plugins, or OSGi bundles?